# gRPC modules not being imported in my project

Tags: go, server, grpc

I'm creating a simple gRPC server in Go and it has the following structure

```
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── proto
    └── consignment
        ├── consignment.pb.go
        └── consignment.proto
```

for some reason, some of the packages I'm using aren't being imported in my app, and when I hover one of them, my IDE says:

```
"google.golang.org/grpc/reflection" in any of 
    /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/reflection (from $GOROOT)
    /home/gabriel/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/reflection (from $GOPATH))
```

I already tried to run lots of commands like:

```
go mod tidy
go get -u
```

but I cannot solve the problem.

I'm pretty new with golang and go modules, and I'm hoping that someone can help me out :)

Comment: Can you build it from the CLI? If so it sounds like the packages are all being imported correctly, and your IDE is misconfigured

Comment: When I try to run the main.go file, everything goes well

Comment: The problem is, I'm not getting autocompletion and all that stuff

Comment: More specifically all the packages that come from "google.golang.org/grpc" simply don't work in the app

Answer (score 0):

Updating VSCode to the latest version solved the problem